# C For Loop Not Working?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, c-strings

I'm working with strings in C as character arrays, and I'm trying to ensure that I can dynamically pass values into my for loops.

The following code works, no problem:

```
for (int i = -6; i < 11; i++) {
    int test = OverlapStrength(fragments[1], fragments[2], i, 0);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

In fact, this code works, too:

```
for (int i = -strlen(fragments[2]) + 1; i < 11; i++) {
    int test = OverlapStrength(fragments[1], fragments[2], i, 0);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

But for some reason, this code doesn't print ANYTHING:

```
for (int i = -strlen(fragments[2]) + 1; i < strlen(fragments[1]); i++) {
    int test = OverlapStrength(fragments[1], fragments[2], i, 0);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

I have checked the values for both `-strlen(fragments[2]) + 1` and `strlen(fragments[1])` just before the loop and they check out to -6 and 11 respectively. Clearly the loop works when I place those values directly into their places, but when I replace the second one with the `strlen` calculations, it breaks and I can't figure out why for the life of me. Help?

**Edit**

OverlapStrength takes its arguments as constants so I can't change them, so I'm pretty sure I'm not changing the fragments as I go. Here's the method declaration:

```
int OverlapStrength(const char one[], const char two[], int startOne, int startTwo)
```

The contents of the fragments shouldn't be important, but they're simply strings that I'm trying to piece back together from overlapping fragments. I have already checked that my fragments are all coming out properly and that their lengths are computed properly when done outside of declaring this loop.

Comment: does `OverlapStrength` change the value of `strlen(fragments[1])` ?

Comment: OverlapStrength's arguments are declared as constants specifically so I can't change them. Editing original post to show that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen` returns value of type `size_t`, which is probably a typedef for `unsigned int` for your case. Then you are comparing a `signed int` (`i`) and `unsigned int` (`strlen(...)`). C decides then to cast your signed value to an unsigned type (because of [default type promotions](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html)). `-6` converted to unsigned int is `4294967290`, therefore your comparison is false, so the loop ends.

To fix this, you can for example cast `strlen` to a signed value, e.g.:

```
i < (int) strlen(fragments[1])
```

Comment: Ah! Ok, @Femaref's answer worked, but yours actually explains to me why. That makes sense, I didn't think of it that way. Thanks!

Comment: liori, you are correct. Should've seen that, normally I'm pro at detecting those casts.

Answer (score 0):

In a for-loop, the codition (the `i < strlen(fragments[1])` part) gets evaluated on every iteration. If `OverlapStrength` changes the value of `fragments[1]` to something less than `i`, the loop will abort.

To fix this, use a constant:

```
int loopUntil = strlen(fragments[1]);
for (int i = -strlen(fragments[2]) + 1; i < loopUntil; i++) {
    int test = OverlapStrength(fragments[1], fragments[2], i, 0);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Comment: My guess here is that `OverlapStrength` isn't executed at all, see my answer. However your code will accidentally also fix this problem, by casting strlen to int.